# keep element positioned when window size changes

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I have two elements, a paragraph and div with img inside, side by side using float.

Currently the image collapses under the paragraph when the browser window shrinks. I'd like to position: fixed but that just moves the image over the existing paragraph to the left.

Is there a way to correct this without resorting to adjusting pixels (relative left x00 etc)

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem? Create a demo using http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

[HTML]

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
 <div id="element1"></div>
 <div id="element2"></div>
 <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
.cleaner{clear: left; line-height: 0; height: 0;} 
#mainWrapper{width: 500px;}
#element1{width: 100px; height: 50px;}
#element2{width: 400px; height: 100px;}
```

This is a simple example, but what I would do is create an element wrapper.  Next I would set it to a pre-determined width. If you'd like, you can set the height as well. Then when the window resizes it will hold the mainWrapper element and preserve the content inside.

I use the cleaner class whenever I float an image.

If you need a more in depth explanation let me know.